# Is training / inference terminology in deep learning any different than train/test in general ML

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I have been reading about "Training and inference" in deep learning.  How is this different then the idea of "Train / Test" in general ML?  In train/test splits the model has not seen the test set of data. Isn't this the same thing as talking about the 'inference' phase of a deep learning model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inference means making predictions using the model. Inference is used during training (the forward pass before back-propagation), and during model evaluation (on the test set), *and when the model is used in production* (to make predictions on new data).

So when people talk about inference *as a phase of development*, it typically means in a production setting, after the model has been trained and evaluated (tested).